# Finding variable length strings in column

Tags: apache-spark

I have a column that looks like this:

```
Class
A
AA
BB
AAAA
ABA
AAAAA
```

What I'd like to do, is filter this column out where it has only A's and nothing else. So the result would be something like this:

```
Class
A
AA
AAAA
AAAAA
```

Is there a way to do this in Spark?

Answer (score 1):

Check below code.

```
scala> val df = Seq("A","AA","BB","AAAA","ABA","AAAAA","BAB").toDF("Class")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [Class: string]

scala> df.filter(!col("Class").rlike("[^A]+")).show
+-----+
|Class|
+-----+
|    A|
|   AA|
| AAAA|
|AAAAA|
+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this using [rlike](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#rlike) function

```scala
 val data1 =
      """
        |Class
        |A
        |AA
        |BB
        |AAAA
        |ABA
        |AAAAA
      """.stripMargin
    val stringDS1 = data1.split(System.lineSeparator())
      .map(_.split("\\|").map(_.replaceAll("""^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$""", "")).mkString(","))
      .toSeq.toDS()
    val df1 = spark.read
      .option("sep", ",")
      .option("inferSchema", "true")
      .option("header", "true")
      .option("nullValue", "null")
      .csv(stringDS1)
    df1.show(false)
    df1.printSchema()

    /**
      * +-----+
      * |Class|
      * +-----+
      * |A    |
      * |AA   |
      * |BB   |
      * |AAAA |
      * |ABA  |
      * |AAAAA|
      * +-----+
      *
      * root
      * |-- Class: string (nullable = true)
      */

    df1.filter(col("Class").rlike("""^A+$"""))
      .show(false)

    /**
      * +-----+
      * |Class|
      * +-----+
      * |A    |
      * |AA   |
      * |AAAA |
      * |AAAAA|
      * +-----+
      */
```